# Prevent Overlapping events in V-calender(Vuetify)

Tags: calendar, vuetify.js

Currently, I am working in project where and i have used V-calender(Vuetify).Where user can click and select event but I want to prevent the overlapping of the event. I saw the documentation and found no props to do this! Can anyone help me out with this!?

[image: This is the current situation]

But I want something like this: [image]

Comment: Do you want to prevent displaying overlapped events or prevent user from adding events that overlap?

Comment: yeah kind of both...

Comment: So in order to prevent user from adding new events you would have to write you custom logic when you add events. Then for displaying you can write your own render function, but since users won't be allowed to create events that won't be needed probably.